# Java mapping classes to arraylists

Tags: java, generics, dictionary, arraylist

I am attempting to map a class of type `T` to an `ArrayList` also of type `T`:

```
Map<Class<?>, ArrayList<?>> map_ = new HashMap<Class<?>, ArrayList<?>>();
```

The problem is that I cannot add an item to an `Arraylist` retrieved from this map:

```
map_.put(A.class, new ArrayList<A>());
A item = new A();
map_.get(item.getClass()).add(item); //failure!
```

How would I go about constructing my map such that I can access and add to the arraylists it contains?

Comment: Take a look at [Java Tutorials: Wildcards](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html)

Comment: You can't do this type-safely.  Accept the need for an unchecked cast somewhere.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473444/can-generics-allow-the-java-compiler-to-check-the-type-of-keys-and-values-in-a-m/1473482#1473482

Answer (score 0):

Change your declaration to:

```
Map<Class<?>, List<Object>> map_ = new HashMap<>();
```

You will have to cast when you `get` *from the lists* because you cannot define a `Map<Class<T>, List<T>> forAll T` in Java, i.e. there is no way to relate the type parameters, so you're forced to use a definition like the one above with casts to do what you want.

Comment: you cannot cast from `List<Object>` to `List<SomethingElse>`

Comment: @newacct I didn't mean cast the `List`, I meant cast the elements returned from `get` on `List<Object>`.

Comment: Yes I think Louis Wasserman was right - I'll have to perform some scary unchecked casts.